# Sum multiple identical tables in mySQL

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I have got 4 identical tables (one for each quarter). I have managed to count each start terminal and group by the start terminal for each quarter. However, I would like to sum all 4 quarters (tables) to get a sum of the counts.

```
SELECT StartTerminal, COUNT(*)
FROM test.2013_q1
GROUP BY StartTerminal;
```

[Click here to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZsDo.png)

Here is the script I have tried to do but failed:

```
SELECT StartTerminal, COUNT(*) as TotalCount
FROM (
    SELECT StartTerminal
    FROM test.2013_q1
    GROUP BY StartTerminal
    UNION ALL
        SELECT StartTerminal
        FROM test.2013_q2
        GROUP BY StartTerminal
    )
    GROUP BY StartTerminal;
```

Thank you!!

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error might be that you have not given a name to your sub query. Please try this -

```
SELECT StartTerminal, SUM(count) as TotalCount
FROM (
SELECT StartTerminal, COUNT(*) as count
FROM test.2013_q1
GROUP BY StartTerminal
UNION ALL
SELECT StartTerminal, COUNT(*) as count
FROM test.2013_q2
GROUP BY StartTerminal
) all_year_data
GROUP BY StartTerminal;
```

Comment: Thanks. All it came back with was "1" and "2" in the total count.

Comment: Did you get your solution?

Comment: No, I didn't. It didn't combine the totals. It just gave me 1 and 2's (I assume a 1 means it was found in one of the tables, and a 2 if it was found in both)

Comment: I have corrected my code after reading again your requirement. Please retry and let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: Hi @Ankit I now have another problem. Please could you help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SUM()` on the counted values, not `COUNT()` on the already grouped ones.

```
SELECT StartTerminal, SUM(cnt) as TotalCount FROM 
    (SELECT StartTerminal, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM test.2013_q1 GROUP BY StartTerminal
UNION ALL
    SELECT StartTerminal, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM test.2013_q2 GROUP BY StartTerminal) AS counted
GROUP BY StartTerminal
```

Comment: Hi, sorry this isn't working either. I get error code 1248: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Just added aliases for the tables. Pls try it again.

Comment: Unfortunately I now get: "Error code 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax" I believe this is on line 4

Comment: @JackMorgan Sry my bad, I should have given an alias as to the unified table. It is corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways to make your query work:
First, you could count the entries in each table and then sum up the results:

```
SELECT StartTerminal, SUM(q_count) FROM
(
SELECT StartTerminal, COUNT(*) AS q_count FROM test.2013_q1 GROUP BY StartTerminal
UNION ALL
SELECT StartTerminal, COUNT(*) AS q_count FROM test.2013_q2 GROUP BY StartTerminal
UNION ALL
SELECT StartTerminal, COUNT(*) AS q_count FROM test.2013_q3 GROUP BY StartTerminal
UNION ALL
SELECT StartTerminal, COUNT(*) AS q_count FROM test.2013_q4 GROUP BY StartTerminal
) as foo
GROUP BY StartTerminal
```

Or you could select all entries from all tables (without grouping in the subqueries!) and then count afterwards:

```
SELECT StartTerminal, COUNT(*) as TotalCount
FROM (
SELECT StartTerminal FROM test.2013_q1
UNION ALL
SELECT StartTerminal FROM test.2013_q2
UNION ALL
SELECT StartTerminal FROM test.2013_q3
UNION ALL
SELECT StartTerminal FROM test.2013_q4
) as foo
GROUP BY StartTerminal;
```